# Unable to run mvn.bat on Jenkins with master/slave on Windows

Tags: java, windows, maven, jenkins, master-slave

I have a master/slave setup running on Windows 2008 RC2. The master doesn't really do anything other than being a master.

The slave I have then runs the build, which works fine for maven projects (Jenkins maven projects). If I create a free-style project I cannot run mvn.bat using a maven target. The exception is that mvn.bat cannot be resolved (path not found).

Maven is installed on the slave through the master, that is, maven was pushed onto the slave through the "install maven" feature.

Does anyone have an idea as to how I can resolve this? I'm using the interface for installing as I do not have access to the system through e.g. remote desktop. Thus I can upgrade/change the maven version for one or more projects, so a system property does not solve my problem on the long run.

Comment: You have the Maven version set in the Job Configuration to something other than "Default", right?

Comment: No, I just used "default". Is that my problem?

Comment: If you select "Default" it will try to find what's installed in the operating system `path`. You said you installed Maven through Jenkins, so you have to pick that installed version from the list in configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Slav wrote, using "Default" as Maven Version will find what is installed on the operating system (that is, somewhere on the system path).

The solution is to select a version and not "Default". I have installed Maven 3.0.5 using the Jenkins installed, selecting this version fixed the issue. Or you could setup the path on the system, but this requires access to the server (which I do not have, only the web interface).